# Unexpected unknown at-rule "@tailwind" scss/at-rule-no-unknown

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css

This is my `stylelint.config.js`,

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['stylelint-config-standard-scss'],
  rules: {
    'at-rule-no-unknown': [
      true,
      {
        ignoreAtRules: ['tailwind']
      }
    ],
    'declaration-block-trailing-semicolon': null,
    'scss/at-extend-no-missing-placeholder': null,
    'color-function-notation': 'legacy',
    'selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown': [
      true,
      {
        ignorePseudoClasses: ['deep']
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And when I run `stylelint "**/*.{scss,css,sass,svelte}"`, I get the following error:

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ stylelint "**/*.{scss,css,sass,svelte}"

src/css/app.scss
 1:1  ✖  Unexpected unknown at-rule "@tailwind"  scss/at-rule-no-unknown
 2:1  ✖  Unexpected unknown at-rule "@tailwind"  scss/at-rule-no-unknown
 3:1  ✖  Unexpected unknown at-rule "@tailwind"  scss/at-rule-no-unknown

error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This is my css file,

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This should be:

```
rules: {
    'at-rule-no-unknown': null,
    'scss/at-rule-no-unknown': [
        true,
        {
            'ignoreAtRules': ['tailwind']
        }
    ],
}
```

> 'scss/at-rule-no-unknown' dissalows unknown at-rules. Should be used instead of Stylelint's at-rule-no-unknown.

[Source](https://github.com/stylelint-scss/stylelint-scss/blob/master/src/rules/at-rule-no-unknown/README.md#at-rule-no-unknown)

Comment: Thanks, for me "'at-rule-no-unknown': null" was not needed. But I don't know how I could have guessed that it needed `scss` in front of the rule name.

Comment: @Tonio edited answer to add source

Comment: Wow, Solved the issue in 1 minite